# Matplotlib.animation performance with Axes3D

Tags: animation, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, mplot3d

I have played with creating HTML5 videos from matplotlib.animation.Artistanimation, it works well for both 2D and 3D images, but for the 3D version, the conversion to html5 video is very slow, like 200s for 35 frames.

Given that it takes roughly 3 times longer to draw a 3D figure than a 2D figure, why does exporting an animation of it would take more than 100 times longer? It would seem that saving a bunch of png files in a loop and creating the animation externally would then be much faster - so is matplotlib handling the export inefficiently?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import time

## Prepare initial data
a = 20
d = 20
tm0 = 10
t_m = tm0 * np.pi/180

def phi(t):
    return np.pi/4 + (6 + 0.1*t) * t

def r(t):
    return d/2 * (1 - phi(t)/phi(t_m))

def Fp(x,y,t):
    return -1/np.sqrt((x + r(t)*np.cos(phi(t)))**2 + \
    (y + r(t) * np.sin(phi(t)))**2)                  \                                      
    -1/np.sqrt((x - r(t)*np.cos(phi(t)))**2 +        \
    (y - r(t)*np.sin(phi(t)))**2)

X = np.arange(-1*a, a)
Y = np.arange(-1*a, a)
x,y=np.meshgrid(X,Y)

## generate image data
imageList = []
for t in range(tm0):
    imageList.append(Fp(x,y,t*np.pi/180))

## Create animation and video from 2D images
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ims = []
for i in range(len(imageList)):
    im = plt.pcolormesh(imageList[i], animated = True)
    ims.append([im])

ani1 = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, blit=True, 
repeat_delay=2000)
plt.colorbar()
t1=time.time()
ani1.to_html5_video()
t2=time.time()
print("2D image to video took: ", t2 - t1)

## Create animation and video from 3D images
t1 = time.time()
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ims = []
for i in range(len(imageList)):
    im = ax.plot_surface(x,y,imageList[i], antialiased=False, animated=True)
    ims.append([im])

ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, blit=True, repeat_delay=2000)
## plt.show()
t2 = time.time()
print("3D animation creation took: ", t2 - t1)
ani.to_html5_video()
t3=time.time()
print("3D animation to video took:", t3 - t2)
```

Comment: A 3D animation is for sure much slower than a 2D animation. Of course it also depends on the amount of data in use, which will have to be projected to the plotting plane for each frame.

Comment: The expensive step is converting animation to html5, which should contain just plain images, right, I hope it is not trying to do some VR here? I understand that it is slower than converting from the 2D images, but at the moment, with 230 frames, it does not seem to finish at all on a MPB with i7 and 16G ram.

Comment: I think in the end this is a valid question. Maybe to reformulate: Given that it takes roughly 3 times longer to draw a 3D figure than a 2D figure, why does exporting an animation of it would take more than 100 times longer? It would seem that saving a bunch of png files in a loop and creating the animation externally would then be much faster - so is matplotlib handling the export inefficiently? I do not know the answer to this, but based on this you may also reformulate the question or open an issue on the matplotlib GitHub tracker.

Comment: This topic is currently being discussed on the matplotlib issue tracker, [issue #10207](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10207).